# whatsapi ruby encoding mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8, whatsapi

I'm using the whatsapi ruby port from https://github.com/ongair/whatsapi, I get the following error trying out the gem in the rails console. My code is in utf8, anyone know how to fix this? The author of the gem is not responding...

Added: The offending code in the is the following:

```
..
elsif count < 256
  @output += "\xf8" + count.chr
..
```

The  @output encoding is utf-8

```
client = Whatsapi::Client.new("41791111111", "", "mynick")
#<Whatsapi::Client:0x00000008ff0bb0 @phone_number="41791111111", @name="mynick", @identity="16d922bd096238946f2b5692fb01a5021eeaefab", @login_status="disconnected", @writer=#<Whatsapi::BinTreeWriter:0x00000008fe8988 @output="">, @reader=#<Whatsapi::BinTreeReader:0x00000008fe8550>>
>> client.connect
#<TCPSocket:fd 7>
>> client.login "asdf"
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/whatsapi-31f8cd9b826a/lib/whatsapi/bin_tree_writer.rb:119:in `write_token'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/whatsapi-31f8cd9b826a/lib/whatsapi/bin_tree_writer.rb:72:in `write_string'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/whatsapi-31f8cd9b826a/lib/whatsapi/bin_tree_writer.rb:61:in `block in write_attributes'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/whatsapi-31f8cd9b826a/lib/whatsapi/bin_tree_writer.rb:60:in `each'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/whatsapi-31f8cd9b826a/lib/whatsapi/bin_tree_writer.rb:60:in `write_attributes'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/whatsapi-31f8cd9b826a/lib/whatsapi/bin_tree_writer.rb:27:in `start_stream'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/whatsapi-31f8cd9b826a/lib/whatsapi/client.rb:54:in `do_login'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/whatsapi-31f8cd9b826a/lib/whatsapi/client.rb:44:in `login'
from (irb):12
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Users/mike/Dropbox/kalenderfee/webapp/bin/rails:4:in `require'
from C:/Users/mike/Dropbox/kalenderfee/webapp/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.30/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:86:in `debug_load'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.30/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:86:in `debug_program'
from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.30/bin/rdebug-ide:121:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```